# How do I reset a user’s password or email them when I create an account?

Tags: emails, users

Is it possible to reset a users password from the Control Panel, I remember seeing an option for that before but not seeing it anymore?

Same goes for notifing users when you create their account, is there a way to trigger an email to them automatically?

If not maybe a plugin is in order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are an administrator or your account has “administrate users” privileges, then there is a checkbox on the user’s edit page in the control panel that says “Require Password Reset on Next Login” which, if checked, will force the users to reset their password the next time they attempt to login.

When creating a new account, if you leave the “Require Email Verification” checkbox checked, the user will get an email asking them to confirm their email address and set a new password on their account when the click the link in the email.

Note that the password reset and account verification process requires email to be configured and working properly under Settings->Email in the control panel.

Comment: Ok thanks brad, im not seeing the "require email validation" checkbox?  I thought maybe it was because of a config setting i had setup but now im not seeing one?  We just have, autoLoginAfterAccountActivation => true, useEmailAsUsername=> true, but even when i turn those of not seeing the "require email verification"

Comment: You probably have “Require Email Verification” turned off globally under Settings->Users->Settings.

Comment: The issue that im having right now is that i have a bunch of users accounts that were created but they were never emailed their passwords?  how do they login?  do they have to go to the forgot your password form first?